# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.EventArgs'

Tags: c#

Before I make my question, I read the similar questions to mine but I couldn't find the answer.

string[][] e = Enumerable.Range(0, 54116).Select(i => new string[2]).ToArray();

I get the `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.EventArgs'` error in following script:

```
for (int k = 0; k <= 54116; k++)
                {
                  int ValueArrayE;
                  ValueArrayE = 0;
                  ValueArrayE = Convert.ToInt32(e[k][0]);  ------->Error
                  int checkuserid = Convert.ToInt32(ValueArrayE);
                  if (checkuserid == InsertedUserId)
                  {
                    titles.Add(e[k][1]);  ------------------------>Error 
                  }
                }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: is this your real code?

Comment: It is only the part that shows the error @Selman22.

Comment: This can't be your real code since `e` is not a `string[][]`. It is either an `EventArgs` or an `EventArgs[]`.

Comment: @Lee: Why can't it be his real code?  He's asking how to solve a compiler error, not a runtime error.

Comment: Most likely, you have a static/member variable called `e` that is a `string[][]`, but you're trying to access it in an event handler that uses `e` as a name for the EventArgs parameter. The parameter - having the same name - will hide the other variable.

Comment: Can you write us what body of method that this code is running in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a parameter of type `EventArgs` named `'e'` in your method.Like this:

```
private void SomeMethod(object s, EventArgs e) // <---
```

Change the name of your array or the parameter and try again.

This might happen if you automatically generate the event handler method using `Visual Studio`, which is giving `e` to the second parameter name.This is the only logical explanation I can think of but I'm surprised why you didn't get any error before those lines.The compiler should give you this error when you declare your array:

> A local variable 'e' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'e', which is already used in a parent or current scope to denote something else.

Comment: If his other `e` is really a private field, it is OK to hide the field with a parameter name `e`. In that case use `this.e` to refer to the field.